# Adding String Resources

Tags: android

```
Note: This string resource has the same name as the element ID: edit_message. However, references to resources are always scoped by the resource type (such as id or string), so using the same name does not cause collisions. "
```

In the  text given above what does "*references to resources are always scoped*" means in context to the following xml snippet

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
```

Comment: uh, show us your strings.xml file....?

Comment: keep change edit_message to edit_mes in String.xml file and try to use in edit text hint android:hint="@string/edit_mes"

Answer (score 0):

**Scoped** to `@id/` and `@string/`

Both your ids are the same, but they do not collide because they are in different scopes

Answer (score 0):

> This string resource has the same name as the element ID: edit_message

Here the String resource has the name as `edit_message` and the Edittext has also the name `edit_message`.

> references to resources are always scoped by the resource type

This means that if you are doing `R.id.edit_message` then it will scope to the **Edittext** `edit_text`. as this is referring to a **id** type.

And if you do `R.string.edit_text` , it will scope to the **String** type `edit_text` because this is referring to a **String** type.

Therefore it is said that ***references to resources are always scoped by the resource type***

Answer (score 0):

It means that both your id and string has same name.But both has two different scope.`@id` will look for `R.id.edit_message` ie id class whereas `@string` will look for `R.string.edit_message`.

So don't worry everything is fine .